# Dynamic Order by SELECT with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the correct MS SQL syntax to select multiple ORDER BY columns when the ORDER BY is based on a CASE statement?

The below works fine with single columns, but I need to sort by multiple columns:

```
SELECT * FROM Products
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 1 THEN Price END ASC,
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 2 THEN Price DESC, Title ASC END <-- problem line
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could try this

```
SELECT * FROM Products
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 1 THEN Price END ASC,
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 2 THEN Price END DESC, 
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 2 THEN Title END ASC
```

Comment: For my particular problem I used `THEN -Price END ASC,` instead of `THEN Price END DESC` as we had to load the sort columns from the same column in the DB. 
So to make it clean we separated each column by a space and used the negative sign as a replacement for `DESC`

Answer (score 6):

@Brad. Pavel was suggesting the following (i think),

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM Products 
              ORDER BY  
              '

IF (@SortIndex = 1) 
    SET @query =@query  + ' Price ASC '
ELSE IF (@SortIndex = 2) 
    SET @query =@query  + ' Price DESC, Title ASC '

sp_executesql @query
```

Why do you think that dynamic sql is not suited for complex stored procedures? Those are exactly the places where you should be using dynamic SQL as it can help reduce the complexity and solve problems such as parameter sniffing. I agree that dynamic sql has its downsides, but i would recommend that you at least give it a try if it works for you.

Comment: The more complex the query gets (especially those dreaded list procedures) with multiple inputs, multiple sort choices, etc., the more reliable results you get from dynamic SQL.

Comment: My only suggestion here is to protect your dynamic queries from injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this as a lower impact on server performance - assuming you have only 2 values at @SortIndex (1 and 2). If not, extend your If with more conditions.

```
If @SortIndex = 1   
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY Price ASC   
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY Price DESC, TITLE ASC 
END
```

Comment: I smell parameters here :).. This solution might actually introduce parameter sniffing

Comment: Assuming that this is a stored procedure and @SortIndex is a parameter to the sproc. And for arguments sake lets say there was another condition - if @SortIndex = 3, then sort by only Tile, and lets say there was one index on price and one on title. Now,if you call the sproc for the first time with @SortIndex = 1, SQL server will create a exec plan that makes use of the index on price. When you call the sproc again, regardless of the value for @SortTitle, SQL server will use the same plan as before. So if @SortTitle = 3, it will still use the index on price even though it is useless here

Comment: I never assumed this is a stored procedure. If it is a simple SQL statement with variable declares and values attribution to variables, then the query should have a good execution plan, depending on which "IF" leaf it will go. The user didn't say that it was a Stored procedure with one parameter; and if it really is - parameter sniffing can be enabled or disabled considering the amount of rows retrieved for each combination.

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite this:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 1 THEN Price END ASC,
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 2 THEN Price DESC, Title ASC END
```

as

```
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 1 THEN Price END ASC,
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 2 THEN Price DESC END, 
Title ASC
```

This adds the added sort column to ALL cases but in my situation, that's what I wanted.

You can also do this (just for example):

```
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 1 THEN Price END ASC,Title ASC,
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 2 THEN Price DESC END
```

Comment: I voted up yrushka's answer. It is a valid option here. But in my case, where I used the above, the user had 12 possible columbs to sort by so this style/option seemed more practical.

Comment: And my above comment would make more sense if I added that the query statement itself was quite involved. It would have been impractical in that case to repeat the whole statment 12 times with different orderby clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Do this ... and say goodbye to your performance. Unfortunately the best solution is to use dynamic sql.

Comment: Care to elaborate? My real application of this for a pretty complex stored procedure where dynamic SQL isn't possible.

Comment: In my experience (just 12 years working with MSSQL), I've run into multiple ocassions, where these constructs produced terrible plans. It's not that is is bad per se, just that I found it unreliable, ie. query that works great today may produce abysmal plans 4 months in the future)