# PLSQL: Multiple values in CASE result

Tags: plsql, case

I am dynamically setting the columns to order on for my PLSQL query, [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15085262/4378740) (and many others like it). I want to add a default case where it sorts on three columns.

Here's my attempt:

```
-- ... long SQL query
--      ps_global_order is the column to sort on, passed in to stored procedure.
--      ps_global_order_dir is the direction to sort on, similarly passed in. 
order by 
  case 
    -- this does not compile (00905 missing keyword):
    when ps_global_order is null then name, phone, email 
    -- this compiles, but I need it on the three columns:
    -- when ps_global_order is null then name  
  end,
  case
    when ps_global_order_dir <> 'ASC' then ''
    when ps_global_order like 'name' then name
  end,
  case
    when ps_global_order_dir <> 'ASC' then ''
    when ps_global_order like 'phone' then phone
  end,
  case
    when ps_global_order_dir <> 'ASC' then ''
    when ps_global_order like 'email' then email
  end,
  case
    when ps_global_order_dir <> 'DESC' then ''
    when ps_global_order like 'name' then name
  end,
  case
    when ps_global_order_dir <> 'DESC' then ''
    when ps_global_order like 'phone' then phone
  end,
  case
    when ps_global_order_dir <> 'DESC' then ''
    when ps_global_order like 'email' then email 
  end
```

Everything is working fine, but I want to specify those three columns to be sorted on.

Is this possible with the `CASE` statement? Must I resort to dynamic SQL or is there a workaround that I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks chakeda.  Bind variables can be used to replace literals, but not for sql objects like tables, columns etc. used in static compilation.  I believe dynamic sql is required to substitute column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
-- ... long SQL query
--      ps_global_order is the column to sort on, passed in to stored procedure.
--      ps_global_order_dir is the direction to sort on, similarly passed in. 
order by 
  case 
    when ps_global_order is null then name
    else null
  end,
  case
    when ps_global_order is null then phone
    else null
  end,
  case
    when ps_global_order is null then email
    else null
  end,
  case
    when ps_global_order_dir <> 'ASC' then null
    when ps_global_order like 'name' then name
  end,
  case
    when ps_global_order_dir <> 'ASC' then null
    when ps_global_order like 'phone' then phone
  end,
  case
    when ps_global_order_dir <> 'ASC' then null
    when ps_global_order like 'email' then email
  end,
  case
    when ps_global_order_dir <> 'DESC' then null
    when ps_global_order like 'name' then name
  end,
  case
    when ps_global_order_dir <> 'DESC' then null
    when ps_global_order like 'phone' then phone
  end,
  case
    when ps_global_order_dir <> 'DESC' then null
    when ps_global_order like 'email' then email 
  end
```

Note that I've replaced all the occurrences of `''` with `NULL`, which is clearer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question so soon, but I figured it out:

```
order by 
    case  when nvl(ps_global_order, ' ') = ' ' then name end,
    case  when nvl(ps_global_order, ' ') = ' ' then phone end,
    case  when nvl(ps_global_order, ' ') = ' ' then email end,
    case
        when ps_global_order_dir <> 'ASC' then ''
    -- continues...
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4154634/4378740) was great help but it was buried in Google results. How this works without the comma eludes me though.

Comment: The comma is there. That's what comes after the `end`.

Comment: I thought so! PLSQL is bizarre.

Comment: That's actually straight SQL. You're sorting on the results of a series of CASE expressions.

Comment: I see now - I thought the comma was a delimiter between case statements. It was a long day