# Laravel 4: order by if post_date not exists then created_at on Listing

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

if I write `orderBy('posting_date','DESC')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')` or `sortByDes('created_at')->sortByDes('posting_date')`, It is just applied on second column name like posting_date, I need to apply `orderBy` on `date` but some `columns` have `created_at` value but `posting_date` is `NULL` while some have `posting_date` while `created_at` is `NULL`, and on frontend I just show the article with recent dates (if posting date exists then posting date else created_at). So how do I order this date By Descending. Thanks in advance.
image of db dates structure:

[image: image of db dates structure]

image of my query:

[image: image of my query]

image of frontend articles listing by recent date:
[image: image of frontend articles listing by recent date]

Comment: I think this thread could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154522/dynamic-order-by-select-with-multiple-columns/4154634#4154634

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = DB::table('articles')
            ->orderByRaw('CASE WHEN posting_date IS NULL THEN created_at ELSE posting_date END DESC')
            ->get();
```

hope answer the question! why don't you using another flag like is_posted in your table, then you be able filter  posted article

Comment: Sorry bro, I seen your answer late but your answer is perfect because I also did same query just difference in my technique is that I created new column like below: $articles = $article->where( 'author', '=', $name )->where( 'status', 'LIKE', 'app%' )->where( 'category', '=', 'main_articles' )->select(DB::raw("* , (CASE WHEN posting_date != '' THEN posting_date ELSE created_at END) AS sort_date"))->orderBy('sort_date','DESC')->get();

Comment: But your query is more simple and perfect than my query, thanks.

Comment: Happy to help :)